# Extracting from new email in Outlook 2010 the native recipients' email addresses

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

The program below is extracting recipient email addresses from a newly composed email account in Outlook 2010. It then inserts them in the email body and it works fine.

However, I want to extract and insert the real addresses only. Now the program takes the addresses such as `John Dow (john@isp.com); John1 Dow (john1@isp.com)` and inserts it in the email body as is.

What I need is to extract the address and insert only the addresses `john@isp.com; john@isp.com` without the full name that preceded each address.

Thanks for your help. Below is the code I am working with -

```
Sub copy_change() 'read the recepients of the new email and add them to the text body where the curser is.

Dim eRecipients As String

eRecipients = Application.ActiveInspector.currentItem.To

Dim objDoc As Word.Document, objSel As Word.Selection
On Error Resume Next

'~~> Get a Word.Selection from the open Outlook item
Set objDoc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
Set objSel = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection

'~~> Type Relevant Text
objSel.TypeText "Recipient : " & eRecipients

Set objDoc = Nothing
Set objSel = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Note that there may be more than two email addresses .

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line

```
eRecipients = Application.ActiveInspector.currentItem.To
```

with

```
dim recip As Recipient
eRecipients = ""
for each recip in Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Recipients
  if Recip.Type = olTo Then
    if (eRecipients <> "") Then eRecipients  = eRecipients  & ", " 
    eRecipients = eRecipients & recip.Address
  End If
next
```

Comment: Dmitry, thanks a lot! It works like a charm. I added Dim to the  "recip As Recipient" statement. Just in case someone else wants to use this code.

Comment: Thanks, I modified the answer above.

Comment: Dmitry, When I added CC email addresses and BCC email addresses to the email, your program grouped them together with the TO email addresses. I would like to copy the TO addresses to one section in the body, the CC addresses in a section below, and the BCC addresses below the CC addresses. Can you advise how to do it. Thanks, Menachem

Comment: You will need to check the Recipient.Type property. See the updated answer above

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it late afternoon and let you know how it went.

Comment: Dmitry, Your code worked again first try! Thanks. 
I am new to VBA outlook and I do not understand why you are coding:  "for each recip in..." Instead of coding: for each Recipient in..." Can you explain. 
Thanks again for the great responses!

Comment: Do you mean why the variable is called recip instead of Recipient? You can name it anything you want.

Comment: Dmitry, I asked this question that has an obvious answer because of something that was not clear to me. Now it is clear to me and thanks for your quick answer.